# problem with reduce and memoisation in javascript hardstructure

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i have to do a task, where i need to  iterate over hardstructure with nested functions arrays objects and other data types. get all the numbers there are in string or not in string into the array and then with reduce method i need to calculate their sum, after calculating their sum i need to do memoisation on this function. but something doesnt work with my reduce even though i have written the most simple task there is, calculating the sum of numbers. my reduce doesnt really calculate the right way it skips some parts of the structure and doesnt gather all of the nubmers also it doesnt really calculate right i think

```
const ex1 = () => ({ a: 13 });
const ex2 = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "a,,,,,,", 2, 2, 2];
const ex3 = () => [...ex2()];
const ex4 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const hardStructure = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: "2",
    c: [
      {
        a: "123",
        b: "@333z$34",
        c: "122,333,4444,5555",
        z: ex4,
        d: [
          [
            123,
            1,
            "1111",
            23323,
            1222,
            55,
            [1212, 1212, 1212],
            {
              a: 111,
              b: null,
              c: () => 111,
              d: 22,
              e: "e",
              f: () => "fffqqq",
            },
          ],
          [
            2212,
            1,
            "111211",
            23,
            121,
            22,
            [33, 3, 3],
            {
              a: 3,
              b: null,
              c: () => 11221,
              d: 2112,
              e: "e11",
              f: () => "fffqqq",
              g: 2,
            },
          ],
          [
            11,
            22,
            "dsds",
            {
              a: {
                b: {
                  c: {
                    d: {
                      a: 1,
                      b: [ex1()],
                      c: {
                        a: {
                          b: {
                            c: {
                              d: {
                                a: new Map([
                                  ["a2134", 2123123],
                                  ["b", 3],
                                  ["c", 3],
                                ]),
                                b: ex2,
                                c: [...ex3(), "1", 1],
                              },
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    d: [
      [
        123,
        1,
        "1111",
        23323,
        1222,
        55,
        [121322332, 12132322, 12323212],
        {
          a: 111,
          b: null,
          c: () => 1123231,
          d: 22,
          e: "e",
          f: () => "fffqqq",
        },
      ],
      [
        2212,
        1,
        "111211",
        23,
        121,
        22,
        [33, 3, 3],
        {
          a: 3,
          b: null,
          c: () => 1123221,
          d: 211,
          e: "e1231",
          f: () => "fffqq1232312123q",
          g: 2123,
        },
      ],
      [
        11,
        22,
        "dsds",
        {
          a: {
            b: {
              c: {
                d: {
                  a: 1,
                  b: [ex1()],
                  c: {
                    a: {
                      b: {
                        c: {
                          d: {
                            a: new Map([
                              [true, 222312],
                              [2, 322],
                              ["c2", 32],
                              [() => {}, 32],
                            ]),
                            b: ex2,
                            c: [...ex3(), "1121123", 1],
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
  {
    a: {
      b: {
        c: {
          d: {
            a: 112312,
            b: [1],
            c: {
              a: {
                b: {
                  c: {
                    d: {
                      a: "",
                      b: "",
                      c: "",
                      v: "v12312323",
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

const numbersArr = [];
const iterate = (hardStructure) => {
  if (hardStructure === null || hardStructure === undefined) {
    return [];
  }
  if (
    hardStructure.constructor === new Set().constructor ||
    hardStructure.constructor === new Map().constructor
  ) {
    console.log("console from map or set");
    hardStructure.forEach((element) => {
      // console.log("123", element);
      return iterate(element);
    });
  }

  if (typeof hardStructure === "function") {
    return iterate(hardStructure());
  }
  if (Array.isArray(hardStructure)) {
    hardStructure.map((items) => {
      return iterate(items);
    });
  }
  if (typeof hardStructure === "object" && !Array.isArray(hardStructure)) {
    for (let key in hardStructure) {
      // console.log(hardStructure[key]);
      return iterate(hardStructure[key]);
    }
  }
  if (typeof hardStructure !== "string") {
    const stringItem = String(hardStructure);
    for (let i = 0; i < stringItem.length; i++) {
      if (!isNaN(+stringItem)) {
        numbersArr.push(+stringItem);
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < hardStructure.length; i++) {
    // console.log(i);
    if (!isNaN(+hardStructure[i])) {
      // console.log("12345678910", isNaN(+hardStructure[2]));
      numbersArr.push(+hardStructure[i]);
    }
  }

  const sumWithInitial = numbersArr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    console.log(accumulator,currentValue)
    return accumulator + currentValue;
  },0);

  //  console.log(numbersArr)
  console.log(sumWithInitial);
  return sumWithInitial;
};

iterate(hardStructure);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements aren't entirely clear, especially as to handling of String and Function properties.  This solution assumes that you want to *call* functions and that you can use `parseInt` for Strings.  If you need to change that, it should be clear enough how and where to do so:

```js
const sumNumbers = (xs) =>
  xs == null
    ? 0
  : xs .constructor == String
    // ? parseInt (xs, 10) || 0 // original version not enough.  Below might not be so either
    ? xs .includes (',') ? sumNumbers (xs .split (',')) : Number (xs .replaceAll (/\D/g, ''))
  : xs .constructor == Number
    ? xs
  : xs .constructor === Array
    ? xs .map (sumNumbers) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  : xs .constructor === Set
    ? sumNumbers ([...xs])
  : xs .constructor === Map
    ? sumNumbers ([...xs .values()])
  : xs .constructor === Function
    ? sumNumbers (xs ()) // or just 0?
  : xs .constructor == Object
    ? sumNumbers (Object .values (xs))
  // TODO: Other types possible here?
    : 0


const ex1 = () => ({a: 13}), 
      ex2 = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "a,,,,,,", 2, 2, 2], 
      ex3 = () => [...[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "a,,,,,,", 2, 2, 2]], 
      ex4 = new Set ([1, 2, 3, 4]), 
      hardStructure = [{a: 1, b: "2", c: [{a: "123", b: "@333z$34", c: "122,333,4444,5555", z: ex4, d: [[123, 1, "1111", 23323, 1222, 55, [1212, 1212, 1212], {a: 111, b: null, c: () => 111, d: 22, e: "e", f: () => "fffqqq"}], [2212, 1, "111211", 23, 121, 22, [33, 3, 3], {a: 3, b: null, c: () => 11221, d: 2112, e: "e11", f: () => "fffqqq", g: 2}], [11, 22, "dsds", {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: 1, b: [{a: 13}], c: {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: new Map ([["a2134", 2123123], ["b", 3], ["c", 3]]), b: ex2, c: [...ex3(), "1", 1]}}}}}}}}}}]]}]}, {d: [[123, 1, "1111", 23323, 1222, 55, [121322332, 12132322, 12323212], {a: 111, b: null, c: () => 1123231, d: 22, e: "e", f: () => "fffqqq"}], [2212, 1, "111211", 23, 121, 22, [33, 3 , 3], {a: 3, b: null, c: () => 1123221, d: 211, e: "e1231", f: ()=> "fffqq1232312123q", g: 2123}], [11, 22, "dsds", {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: 1, b: [{a: 13}], c: {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: new Map ([[true, 222312], [2, 322], ["c2", 32], [() => {}, 32]]), b: ex2, c: [...ex3 (), "1121123", 1]}}}}}}}}}}]]}, {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: 112312, b: [1], c: {a: {b: {c: {d: {a: "", b: "", c: "", v: "v12312323"}}}}}}}}}}]

console .log (sumNumbers (hardStructure))
```

We have four base cases:

- on a nil value (`null` or `undefined`), we return `0`
- on a `Number`, we return its value
- on a `String`, we call `parseInt` on it and return the value.  This is the part I think you would most likely need to change
- on an unknown type (perhaps a regular expression or a date), we return `0`

The others are recursive case:

- for an `Array`, we recursively call our function on each element and then total them together.
- for a `Function`, we call the function with no arguments, and recur on the result.
- for our other known types (`Object`, `Set`, `Map`), we extract its values into an `Array` and recur on the result.

Comment: if we iterate over string with symbols for example b: "@333z$34" this it doesnt get number from it

Comment: Note, *"This is the part I think you would most likely need to change"*.  What are your requirements?  What number is that supposed to represent?  What happens if there are more digits than allowed in a JS number?  Is `"122,333,4444,5555"` supposed to represent one 14-digit number or four shorter ones?  This answer is not a final solution to your problem, but it should make it clear how to write such a solution, once you get such requirements nailed down.

Comment: It should represent four short ones as it is also when i console log i think reduce doesnt calculate it the right way because it starts summing numbers it starts the right way but suddenly turns to 0 and then starts summing again with nee numbers not remembering the previous ones my taks is to get all numbers there are in string or not in string gather them in an array and calculate the sum after that i need to add memoisation

Comment: And what would you expect for the string `"123.45,6.7.8,  9.10#11"`?  We can't code it if we don't understand the possibilities.

Comment: We should get everything except dots and # this

Comment: So no decimals points allows?  And what about commas here?  Is this equivalent of `1234567891011` or of `[12345, 678, 91011]` or of something else?

Comment: I want to do it with shorter version the seccond one

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by that.  The general point is that you really need to specify the algorithm for handling Strings.  Updated with my best guess so far.

Comment: First you need to use recursion to get an array that will contain absolutely all the numbers from this data
[12:43 PM] Then with reduce you need to calculate their sum
[12:44 PM] And at the end you need to add memoization to these calculations

Comment: this is the exact task i have

Comment: I did not try to do your homework for you, solving it in a way that made sense to me.  My technique should be easy enough to modify to return an array of numbers.  But useful memoization is going to be problematic.  If you are allowing arbitrary functions as data, then it might well be impossible.

Comment: BTW, to get numbers from this instead of a total, simply replace the `map`-then-`reduce` call for `Array`s with `xs .flatMap (sumNumbers)`.